# CSS remove unused styling

Tags: css, performance, minify

I often override "base" css styling by adding an (example) `override.css` below the `base.css` in the `head` of my sites.

`base.css`:

```
a { color: blue; }
```

And then later in `override.css`:

```
a { color: red; }
```

This might be bad practice, but in my experience a very common way of doing it in most websites. In this very simplified case the css-file would be double the size of what it could be.

Are there any automated tools to remove all unused styling, and only present a "parsed" css-file to the visitors? Would for example example CSS CCC option in Prestashop do this for me?

Comment: such tools could be useless for me because you can never know *all the unused styling,* ... what if you have some JS code that dynamically add classe or new element ? what if you run a CMS and always adding new content, etc ? And a CSS file won't be a huge file if it's well written ... so doing a compressing and some caching will be enough for performance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for an automatic method, https://github.com/giakki/uncss

However, chrome devtools also includes a nice panel for seeing all unused styles, so most likely it's better to do it manually through this. How to use the coverage panel: https://blog.logrocket.com/using-the-chrome-devtools-new-code-coverage-feature-ca96c3dddcaf